# How can I set custom http headers with tungstenite-rs?

Tags: http, rust

I need to listen to a websocket, however, for the websocket to work, some http header must be set during the request.

I tried to search for any useful information in docs.rs and on the github issues, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Maybe [`accept_hrd`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/fn.accept_hdr.html) is able to do what you do?

Answer (score 1):

So, this [issue #92](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/issues/92) pointed me in the correct direction for figuring this out. First of all, the [`connect`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/client/fn.connect.html) method for [`tungstenite`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/index.html) takes a generic argument, with the trait constraint [`IntoClientRequest`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/client/trait.IntoClientRequest.html). The easiest way to add your own headers following this logic would be to use the [`http`](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/) crate as its request type implements said trait.

Add this to `cargo.toml`:

```ini
tungstenite = "0.20.1"
http = "0.2.9"
```

And then to create a new request with headers:

```rust
use tungstenite::handshake::client::generate_key;

let req = http::Request::builder()
    .uri("wss://some.uri/path")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", self.protocol.to_string())
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", generate_key());
```

Now, this should generally work, but my solution also required implementing [`IntoClientRequest`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/client/trait.IntoClientRequest.html) for my value and building it, because, for some reason, tungstenite does not come with builders. All my solution does is create the same builder as shown above, convert it to [`tungstenite`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/index.html) [`Request`](https://docs.rs/tungstenite/latest/tungstenite/handshake/client/type.Request.html) type, and return it from the `IntoClientRequest` trait. Here it is:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use http::{Uri, Version};
use tungstenite::{client::IntoClientRequest, handshake::client::generate_key};

pub struct WampRequest<T: ToString> {
    pub uri: T,
    pub protocol: T
}

impl<T: ToString> IntoClientRequest for WampRequest<T> {
    fn into_client_request(self) -> tungstenite::Result<tungstenite::handshake::client::Request> {
        let uri = Uri::from_str(&self.uri.to_string())?;
        let req = http::Request::builder()
            .uri(self.uri.to_string())
            .version(Version::HTTP_11)
            .header("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", self.protocol.to_string())
            .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", generate_key())
            .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
            .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
            .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", 13)
            .header("Host", uri.host().unwrap());
        Ok(tungstenite::handshake::client::Request::from(req.body(())?))
    }
}
```

Edit: One thing I did not realize until runtime, is that `tungstenite` does not add `Sec-Websocket-Key` if you do it like this, so I have edited the code to show how to manually add in the `Sec-Websocket-Key`, which thankfully tungstenite made that interface public. So this will not work if you do not add that header.

Edit 2: So much like my first edit, I ran into more runtime errors but now I can say with 100% certainty that the code provided at least works for my personal use-cases. Specifically though, there were panics because websocket protocol requires the values exist but it does not create them automatically when you create your own headers, you must add them, my implementation works for a version 1 WAMP router at least.